# Selenium vs Protractor - how to choose

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, interview, protractor

**Selenium or Protractor?**

In what circumstances is Protractor a better tool for testing a web application than Selenium?

I often see interview questions about Selenium, but Protractor seems to me to be easier to use to automate web applications.

Are there types of web applications that work better with Protractor than Selenium?

Comment: In my personal opinion, I do not think there is a "better" tool. Each tool has got its purpose, and if a given tool is applied in a wrong contextual environment, we consider it less-good.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it much less opinion-based. You can revert my edits if you wish, but as originally written the question is likely to stay closed.

Answer (score -1):

Experienced QA Engineer also knows the answer - can articulate pro and cons of both. Memorizing the answer provided by others would be only valuable for someone who has no experience but wants to fake it in interview.